# Error with qgis2threejs plug-in

Tags: qgis, 3d

I am currently endeavouring to use qgis2threejs to create a 3D visual using DSM and orthomosaic data captured using my unmanned aircraft system (UAS). Originally the plug-in seemed to work perfectly, as you can see by my results here: http://paulgeorgie.com/culzean.html

Having now updated the plug-in via the QGIS repository to version 0.7.2, I can no longer seem to get it to work.  The output HTML file still shows a 3D DSM however the orthomosaic is now just entirely black.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Is it related to the amount of data I'm trying to process perhaps?

Or the plug-in?

Or my hardware?

As for hardware, my desktop is currently running Windows 8.1 on an i7-5820k (Haswell-e) CPU with 32Gb DDR4 RAM and Powercolor Radeon R9 290X 4096MB GDDR5 Graphics Card. My Asus Zenbook also encountered the same issue.

Comment: please note: having un-installed / re-installed previous versions (0.7.0), this problem still persists on my system.

Answer (score 1):

The `.html, .js`and`.css` files that the `Qgis2threejs` plugin generates are saved as files created on `Unix/Linux`, which means that they have different line endings than the ones created on `DOS/Windows`.

Unix systems represent a newline with `LF` (Line Feed), while DOS uses `CR` (carriage return) + `LF` at the end of the line code.

On UNIX:

```
   <html>LF
   <head>LF
   <meta charset="UTF-8">LF
```

On DOS/Windows:

```
   <html>CRLF
   <head>CRLF
   <meta charset="UTF-8">CRLF
```

What you need to do is to make an **EOL Conversion** (End Of Line) between Unix/Windows format to all the files that the plugin creates.

At least, that's what worked for me.